Convert one column to two columns
I have a string like this: "1247,3-1243,4" and with string split convert to table like this:

How could I split each row into two columns with , separator - like this:

Maybe I need to use CROSS APPLY or STRING_SPLIT? Could someone help me please?

You Must NOT Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In An English Text !

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Add data example as text or DDL/DML instructions and your current attempt (query). You can use cross apply  and string_split twice and then pivot.

this query could solved my problem:  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PersonnelID) Number,                SUBSTRING(t.value, 1, CHARINDEX(',', t.value) - 1) AS personnelID,                SUBSTRING(t.value, CHARINDEX(',', t.value) + 1, LEN(t.value)) AS JobTypeID         FROM STRING_SPLIT('1247,3-12473,4', '-') t;
